# ExtJS Grid : why the focused line also selected it?

Tags: javascript, extjs, grid

I've trouble with grid holding on the left the special column for row selection, we need indeed multiple selection through those checkboxes
see the second grid here as sample : [See on Sencha](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/example/grid/grid-plugins.html)

When a row on the grid receive the "Windows" focus (either by playing with the mouse either with one or more hit on the TAB key), the grid highlights it which is correct but it also checks it which is not a good idea (the user may have to uncheck it, checks other ones and then ask for an operation on the selected rows). My question is how to change this behavior ? So no
selection on focus ! Only obviously if the user click on the checkboxes !

Thanks

Comment: left column is like a actioncolumn it has a button which will listens to its click event

Answer (score 1):

Use [`checkOnly: true`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.selection.CheckboxModel-cfg-checkOnly) (it is `false` by default):

```
selModel: {
    selType: 'checkboxmodel',
    checkOnly: true
},
```

Example: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/sjn

Comment: Thanks, you saved my day !-)

Comment: I guess you could tick the answer then :)

Comment: No problem, though I'd appreciate if you retry once earned a bit more reputation :)